# Why is my recursion producing an unexpected error? And how to amend the recursion when a loop has been reached?

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I am writing code that I believe is recursion as per below. The aim of the code is to take some integer n, and to determine whether it is a 'happy' number. A 'happy' number is one where the sum of the square of it's digits eventually equal to 1.

For example 19 is a happy number because 1^2 + 9^2 = 82      8^2 + 2^2 = 68     6^2 + 8^ 2 = 100   1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1.

```
n= 234
def square_sum(n):
    total_sum = 0
    for i in str(n):                
        square_char = int(i) **2    
        total_sum += square_char

return square_sum(n)

def loop_the_above(n):
    while n > 1:
         n = square_sum(n)

loop_the_above(n)
```

I am getting an error above for the line "while n > 1";  this is the error:

```
"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' " ; why is this the case?
```

Also, can someone please amend the code above, the first batch runs fine, but I cannot seem to get the second batch (recursion I believe) to run- I believe that the code is not quite correct.
I would like the recursion to stop, once the same number has been reached twice, because this indicates that we have reached a loop, and that the number is no longer a 'happy' number as it will never reach 1.

Comment: `return square_sum(n)` what does this line mean?

Comment: The code formatting must be wrong, as you have a `return` outside a function. In the return, you are calling `square_sum` again, indeed using recursion, but that would loop forever, as you have no base case for the recursion, nor are you changing the arg you call the recursive function. You should probably call `square_sum(total_sum)` (and add the base case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining if a number is a happy number can be difficult as one might end up in an endless cycle. For example for `20`:

```
20 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> ... and so on
```

You can track cycles by remembering the numbers from each step.

**Recursive approach**

```py
def is_happy_number(n: int, seen=[]) -> bool:
    if n == 1:
        return True
    square_sum = sum(int(digit) ** 2 for digit in str(n))
    if square_sum in seen:
        return False
    seen.append(square_sum)
    return is_happy_number(square_sum, seen)


print(is_happy_number(19))  # True
print(is_happy_number(20))  # False
print(is_happy_number(201231123))  # False
```

---

**Iterative approach**

Recursion is not so sexy, let's get rid of it:

```py
def is_happy_number2(n: int) -> bool:
    seen = set()
    while n != 1 and n not in seen:
        seen.add(n)
        n = sum(int(digit) ** 2 for digit in str(n))
    return n == 1
```

---

**Constant space approach**

The only 1-digit numbers that are happy are `1` and `7`. Let's take that into account.

```py
def is_happy_number(n: int) -> bool:
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(int(digit) ** 2 for digit in str(n))

    return n in (1, 7)
```

Comment: `seen` is best implemented as a `set` for faster O(1) testing.

Comment: Excellent remark @Booboo, I've taken that into account in the **iterative approach**